# Why CentOS 6 adjusts console width when running screen?

Tags: gnu-screen, console, centos

I run a console window through my PuTTY session.

That console windows has a column width of 140.

When I start the screen session, the console shrinks to 80 columns.

I do not see this behavior on CentOS 5, only on CentOS 6.

Does anybody know what has to be tweaked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, forgot to answer with my own solution to this problem.

Turns out CentOS 6 disables this line in its `/etc/screenrc` script:

```
termcapinfo  xterm Z0=\E[?3h:Z1=\E[?3l:is=\E[r\E[m\E[2J\E[H\E[?7h\E[?1;4;6l
```

I was able to restore the functionality by putting this line into my local `~/.screenrc` file.

Here is the content of my `~/.screenrc` file in its entirety

```
# Fix termcapinfo for xterm to allow column resizing
# xterm emulation is used by PuTTY

termcapinfo  xterm Z0=\E[?3h:Z1=\E[?3l:is=\E[r\E[m\E[2J\E[H\E[?7h\E[?1;4;6l
```

If you are a sysadmin, you may want to put this `.screenrc` file into `/etc/skel` directory, and home directories of existing users.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, init sequence in screen's terminal description includes an explicit request to set 80-column mode -- `\033 [ ? 3 l`.   Check contents of is/is2 sequences in terminfo string when running screen -- either `echo $TERMINFO` or `infocmp` should show that.

Answer (score 0):

This was discussed in a Debian bug report: [#435715
Remove window resize from 'putty'](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=435715):

> The escape code (CSI ? 3 l) sets 80-column mode, forcing a window
>   resize. This is not appropriate for a reset sequence.

which was inconclusive because PuTTY's developers did not participate:

> It seems there was nothing from the putty developers so we will keep
>   this terminfo line the same.

The relevant documentation for the reset-strings is in [`terminfo(5)`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/terminfo.5.html#h3-Tabs-and-Initialization), e.g.,

> Most  initialization  is  done with **`is2`**.  Special terminal
>   modes can be set up without duplicating strings by putting
>   the  common  sequences in **`is2`** and special cases in **`is1`** and
>   **`is3`**.
>
> A set of sequences that does a harder reset from a totally
>   unknown state can be given as **`rs1`**, **`rs2`**, **`rf`** and **`rs3`**, analogous to **`is1`**,  **`is2`**,  **`if`**  and  **`is3`**  respectively.   These
>   strings  are  output  by  the [**`reset`**](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tset.1.html#h3-reset---reinitialization) program, which is used
>   when the terminal gets into a wedged state.  Commands  are
>   normally  placed  in **`rs1`**, **`rs2`** **`rs3`** and **`rf`** only if they produce annoying effects on the screen and are not  necessary
>   when  logging  in.   For  example,  the command to set the
>   vt100 into 80-column mode would normally be part  of  **`is2`**,
>   but  it causes an annoying glitch of the screen and is not
>   normally needed since the terminal is usually  already  in
>   80 column mode.

Because this is a matter of *taste* rather than an *error*, and because one of PuTTY's developers chose to use this method for resetting the terminal (and none of the others participated in the subsequent discussion), there was no reason to change the initialization style.